# Get inline object key and value

Tags: c#, loops, object, foreach

I am new in c# and stucked with geting object key and value in loop, i can't even create proper working loop that goes through object records.

Main function that define object

```
void Auth()
{
    var data = new {
        username = Username.text, 
        password = Password.text
    };

    networkManager.SendData("LOGIN", data);
}
```

after that data object going through multiple functions and finally comes to this function.

```
    public string format(object nObject)
    {
        foreach (var row in nObject) {
            Debug.Log(row.Key);
        }
    }
```

is there any way to create simple object and loop through it outside main function  and retrive Key (username, password) and Value (Username.text, Password.text) both as strings also want notice that object not always will contain same data, basically i want simply manipulate with data inside object.

Or maybe there is some other better/correct way to do this ?

Please advise.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a key/value map, in which case an anonymous object probably isn't what you're looking for.  Maybe you should be using a `StringDictionary` or `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to enumerate via all pair field and it value.
 Because you passing anonymous type I see two options: via reflection and via object deserialization via JSON.
First approach:

```
public void format(object nObject)
{
    foreach (var row in nObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Debug.Log($"Key{row.Name}={row.GetValue(nObject)}");
    }
}
```

The second approach is good if you are planing to use complex value types:

```
public void format(object nObject)
{
    var obj = JObject.FromObject(nObject);
    foreach (var row in obj)
    {
        var key = row.Key;
        string value;
        switch (row.Value.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Array:
                value = ((JArray) row.Value).Count.ToString();
                break;
            case JTokenType.Boolean:
                value = ((Boolean)row.Value)? "Да" : "Нет";
                break;
            default:
                value = row.Value.ToString();
                break;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Key{key}={value}");
    }
}
```

Here I use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary, and loop it with a foreach

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDic)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

You should look at the MS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)